# tensorflow bert 'tuple' object has no attribute problem

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model

from tensorflow_text.tools.wordpiece_vocab import bert_vocab_from_dataset as bert_vocab
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 1028

text_dataset = tf.keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory(pathlib.Path('path').parent,
labels="inferred", label_mode="int", batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
text_examples = tf.keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory(pathlib.Path('anotherpath').parent, subset='both',
labels="inferred", label_mode="int", batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, validation_split=0.2, seed=2)

bert_tokenizer_params=dict(lower_case=True)
reserved_tokens=["[PAD]", "[UNK]", "[START]", "[END]"]

bert_vocab_args = dict(
# Arguments for `text.BertTokenizer`
bert_tokenizer_params=bert_tokenizer_params,
vocab_size=1048576,
reserved_tokens=reserved_tokens,
# Arguments for `wordpiece_vocab.wordpiece_tokenizer_learner_lib.learn`
learn_params={},
)

train_examles = text_dataset, text_examples
myvocab = bert_vocab.bert_vocab_from_dataset(
train_examles, **bert_vocab_args)

def write_vocab_file(filepath, vocab):
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
for token in vocab:
print(token, file=f)

write_vocab_file('vocab.txt', myvocab)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".py", line 28, in 
myvocab = bert_vocab.bert_vocab_from_dataset(
File ".venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_text\tools\wordpiece_vocab\bert_vocab_from_dataset.py", line 82, in bert_vocab_from_dataset
element_spec = dataset.element_spec
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'element_spec'

try write vocab from https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/subwords_tokenizer?hl=ru, but cant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.